# Flash AS3. Problems with removing EventListener

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, events

So I have a bit of a problem here. I will use fake variable names in the codes I'll show to make it simpler. But, I made a function that is called once by certain conditions that are not important to specify. This function creates a variable that is a Function itself. Then, I call a timer eventListener for this function variable to call it in a 'loop'. It works for that part. But then, I want to remove this event listener, but it does not recognize the variable of the function ( that I sent as an argument ) in this timer function. It shows null and it mean I cannot remove the eventListener and the function keeps being called forever. Any solutions?

P.S. myTimer is a public variable available everywhere and I get a 1010 error.

```
public function calledOnce(){
    this.myFunction = loopFunction( x, y, "function" );
    this.myTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, this.myFunction );
}
public function loopFunction( refX, refY, refFunction ){
    return function( e: Event ){
        //Do something
        switch( refFunction ){
            case "function":
                this.myTimer.removeEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, this.myFunction );
                break;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I had to actually copy and paste it because I thought it would work indeed. Maybe somebody can explain it. However, if this doesn't work, what's the need of making it in this way? Can't you just change your code that a function is not returned? Upvoting this because I am curious about the explanation, too.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it has something to do with `this`. If you `trace (this);` you would get `[object YourClass]` but when you do that inside the function like so:

```
public function loopFunction( refX, refY, refFunction ){
    return function( e: Event ){
        trace (this);
        //Do something
        switch( refFunction ){
            case "function":
                myTimer.removeEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, myFunction );
                break;
        }
    };
}
```

You get `[global]` instead and I have a feeling your class object is no longer there in that scope. I managed to get it running by getting rid of the `this` and declaring the variables explicitly:

```
private var myFunction:Function;
private var myTimer:Timer = new Timer (1000);

public function calledOnce(){
    myFunction = loopFunction( x, y, "function" );
    myTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, this.myFunction );
}
public function loopFunction( refX, refY, refFunction ){
    return function( e: Event ){
        //Do something
        switch( refFunction ){
            case "function":
                myTimer.removeEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, myFunction );
                break;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a ready-made function code, without any reference to those `refX, refY, refFunction` as they are unavailable within the generated function.

```
public function loopFunction( refX, refY, refFunction ){
    switch( refFunction ){
        case "function":
            return function( e: Event ){
                //Do something
                myTimer.removeEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, myFunction );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware though that removing a dynamically generated listener isn't easy, to do that, you first have to store the function somewhere (you already have there code to store it in a variable `myFunction`).